# Extraction of Data using tbodyclass and Beautifulsoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Extraction with tbody class using BeautifulSoup and Python 3.

Im trying to extract the table (summary) on top of it. Im using BeautifulSoup for extraction. However I get the following error while using tclass to extract the table containing name,age,info etc

I am aware I can use the previous table{class :datatable} to extract the table .However I want to try extracting using tbody class

How do i extract the table with tbodyclass and what error am i making?
Im bit new to web scraping and any  detailed help would be appreciated

Here is the code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

urls=['https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/company- officers/GOOG.O',
      'https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/company- officers/AMZN',
      'https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/company- officers/AAPL']

for item in urls:
   response=requests.get(item)
   data=response.content
   soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
   required_data=soup.find_all(class_='moduleBody')
   real_data=required_data.find_all(tbodyclass_='dataSmall')
   print(real_data)
```

Here is the Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\scrape.py", line 15, in <module>
real_data=required_data.find_all(tbodyclass_='dataSmall')
 File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
 packages\bs4\element.py", line 1620, in __getattr__
"ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're 
probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call 
find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Comment: Do you expect to get the table containing biographies as well or only the table under summary?

Answer (score 1):

To target only be `tbody` you need to select only the first match for that `tbody` class. So you can use `select_one`.

```
table = soup.select_one('table:has(.dataSmall)')
```

gets you the table without the table tags and you can still loop `trs` and `tds` within to write out table. I show using pandas though to handle below.

---

Looks like you can use pandas

```
import pandas as pd

urls=['https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/company- officers/GOOG.O',
      'https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/company- officers/AMZN',
      'https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/company- officers/AAPL']
for url in urls:
    table = pd.read_html(url)[0]
    print(table)
```

---

Combining using pandas and the tbody class but pulling in parent table tag

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

urls=['https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/company- officers/GOOG.O',
      'https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/company- officers/AMZN',
      'https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/company- officers/AAPL']
with requests.Session() as s:
    for url in urls:
        r = s.get(url)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        table = soup.select_one('table:has(.dataSmall)')
        print(pd.read_html(str(table)))
```

---

Ignoring table tag (but adding later for pandas to parse) - you don't have to and can loop tr and td within rather than handover to pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

urls=['https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/company- officers/GOOG.O',
      'https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/company- officers/AMZN',
      'https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/company- officers/AAPL']
with requests.Session() as s:
    for url in urls:
        r = s.get(url)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        table = soup.select_one('.dataSmall')
        print(pd.read_html('<table>' + str(table) + '</table>'))
```

Comment: Good Solution. However Im trying to do it using bs4

Comment: The above does do it using bs4. You only need to loop tr and tds rather than pass to pandas (see bottom two versions)

Comment: Thanks.Very Helpful

Comment: Pandas just gives a nice formatted output after you do the initial work with bs4 as in this case the looping of trs and tds is a bit of a pain to get nice output.

Comment: I just dabbled in pandas. Looks like I need to go deeper.

Answer (score 1):

To get the table under `summary`, you can try the following script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URLS = [
    'https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/company- officers/GOOG.O',
    'https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/company- officers/AMZN',
    'https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/company- officers/AAPL'
]

for url in URLS:
    r = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    for items in soup.select_one("h3:contains(Summary)").find_parent().find_next_sibling().select("table tr"):
        data = [' '.join(item.text.split()) for item in items.select("th,td")]
        print(data)
```

Comment: very nice there I see and you accounted for the th! Bit of a mind bender path to follow for the select ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
required_data.find_all("tbody", class_="dataSmall")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `findall()` function returns a set of results. This is useful when more than one occurrence of the tag is present.
You need to iterate over the results, and using `findall()` on each one separately:

```py
for item in urls:
   response = requests.get(item)
   data = response.content
   soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
   required_data = soup.find_all(class_='moduleBody')
   for res in required_data:
    real_data = res.find_all(tbodyclass_='dataSmall')
    print(real_data)
```

Edit: One find_all is enough:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = ["https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/company-officers/GOOG.O", "https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/company-officers/AMZN.O", "https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/company-officers/AAPL.O"]
for URL in url:
    req = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
    for i in soup.find_all("tbody", {"class": "dataSmall"}):
        print(i)
```

Comment: With this I get an empty list 18 times

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what information you are trying to extract, but doing:

```
for res in required_data:
   real_data=res.find_all("tbody", class_="dataSmall")
   for dat in real_data:
       print(dat.text.strip())
```

outputs lots of info about lots of people...

EDIT: If you're looking for the summary table, you need this:

```
import pandas as pd

tabs = pd.read_html(url)    
print(tabs[0]
```

and there's your table.

Comment: Im trying to extract the table just below the stock price of the company. The table starts with summary and has list of info on directors,VP etc

Comment: How do i go from here to getting only the table informatrtion?

Comment: @Akshay - If you're just looking for that, see edit answer.

Comment: Thanks @Jack Fleeting